# Does passing a slice to golang from c do a memory copy?

Tags: go, cgo

I need to pass a big chunk for float32 (or byte) from C to a go library.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
        "C"
        "fmt"
)

//export PrintInt                                                                                                     
func PrintInt(x []float32) {
        fmt.Println(x)
}

func main() {}
```

After compile it with `go build -buildmode=c-archive foo.go`

I got `foo.h`, here of a part of it:

```
typedef GoInt64 GoInt;
typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;

#endif

/* End of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


extern void PrintInt(GoSlice p0);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

You can see that type `GoSlice` in `foo.h` holds a pointer to the data (`void *data`). So does the implementation of `PrintInt` in `foo.h` do an implicit copy of that data?

Comment: How are you passing a slice from C to Go? If you're creating the slice header in C, the answer should be obvious, because the slice header contains the pointer to the underlying array.

Comment: @JimB You are probably right, it's the most reasonable implementation. But the interface does not forbid the implementation to make a copy.

Comment: There would be no expectation that that could happen. Neither C nor Go would ever implicitly allocate new memory, copy the associated array, and pass a _different_ value to a function. Go is pass by value in all cases, and here the value is the slice header, nothing else.

Comment: @JimB "Neither C nor Go would ever implicitly allocate new memory" Could you let me know if this is documented somewhere? I want to be certain next time I hit similar question.

Comment: I think it's documented by the fact that if the memory were copied, the struct would be different, because the pointer value would have to change. It would be very strange to pass a value to a function and have the function receive a _different_ value. Would you expect passing a plain pointer to dereference and copy every value recursively, and then somehow receive a new pointer in the function? There are an infinite number of things a language implementation could do, but not every possibility can be documented.

Comment: @JimB That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I tried to modify the data from go side, it is reflected in C. So they share same memory.

foo.go:

```
package main

import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
)

//export PrintInt
func PrintInt(x []float32) {
    fmt.Println(x)
    for i := range x {
        x[i] = -float32(i)
    }
}

func main() {}
```

foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "foo.h"

int main() {
  float bar[32];
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    bar[i] = i;
  }

  GoSlice s;
  s.data = (void*)bar;
  s.len = 32;
  s.cap = 32;
  PrintInt(s);

  for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    printf("%f ", bar[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

With command:

```
go build -buildmode=c-archive foo.go
cc foo.c foo.a -o 123 && ./123
```

I got output:

> [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
>   26 27 28 29 30 31]
>   -0.000000 -1.000000 -2.000000 -3.000000 -4.000000 -5.000000 -6.000000 -7.000000 -8.000000 -9.000000 -10.000000 -11.000000 -12.000000 -13.000000 -14.000000 -15.000000 -16.000000 -17.000000 -18.000000 -19.000000 -20.000000 -21.000000 -22.000000 -23.000000 -24.000000 -25.000000 -26.000000 -27.000000 -28.000000 -29.000000 -30.000000 -31.000000